# (1)In function ‘main’:(2) warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]

Tags: c, pointers, printf

What is  wrong with my code?

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main(void){
        int a;
        int *p;
        p=&a;
        printf("%d\n",p);
   }
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n",p);` --> `printf("%d\n",*p);`

Comment: Whats wrong: %d expects int but you pass an int*. Read the compiler warning. It can't get much clearer.

Comment: what should I do to print out the address of a?

Comment: `printf("%d\n",p);` --> `printf("%p\n",(void*)p);`

Comment: [man printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) or read a book.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` format specifier in `printf()` expects an `int` argument. In your code you're passing a `int *`. You need to either

- Dereference the pointer to get an `int` type, if you want to print the value stored in the memory location pointed by the pointer.
- use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void *`, if you want to print the pointer.

It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to pass a wrong type of argument to any format specifier.